# visual studio 2012 don't support list initialize of unordered_set(c++ stl)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

template<class T>
T cmerge (T a, T b) { T t(a); t.insert(b.begin(),b.end()); return t; }

int main ()
{
    std::unordered_set<std::string> first;                                // empty
    std::unordered_set<std::string> second ( {"red","green","blue"} );    // init list
    std::unordered_set<std::string> third ( {"orange","pink","yellow"} ); // init list
    std::unordered_set<std::string> fourth ( second );                    // copy
    std::unordered_set<std::string> fifth ( cmerge(third,fourth) );       // move
    std::unordered_set<std::string> sixth ( fifth.begin(), fifth.end() ); // range

    std::cout << "sixth contains:";
    for (const std::string& x: sixth) std::cout << " " << x;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This segment of code(copy from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/unordered_set/) cannot correctly compiled under visual studio 2012. I wonder whether visual studio support the feature that can list initialize of unordered_set(or other containers of stl)? Please tell me answers,thanks!

Comment: This is C++11, and I'm pretty sure VS 2012... isn't.

Comment: Although VS 2012 implements *some* C++11 features, it's nowhere close to complete. For this code, you really need 2013 instead (with which it works just fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VC11 (Visual Studio 2012) does not support initializer lists.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx

You need Visual Studio 2013 for that, which implements this and many other C+11 features.